# NestJS / Typescript error TS2304 - Cannot find name 'Get'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am getting this error to compile a file.

> [ERROR] 17:58:11 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: src/main.ts(5,6):
> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Get'.

This is is my `main.ts` file

```
import {Controller, Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import {NestFactory} from "@nestjs/core";
@Controller()
class AppController {
    @Get()
    getRootRoute() {
        return "Hi, there!";
    }
}

@Module({
    controllers: [AppController]
})
class AppModule {}

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

    await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap()
```

Comment: Have you imported `Get` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import `Get` from the `@nestjs/common` package